Grafana timeout/logout after a specific time
In my company we use Grafana for some graphics, we use it in a TV with the Grafana Kiosk mode, the problem is that after a certain time it kicks out of the session, and we have to log in every time.
I want to know if there's a way to always keep the session on, if there's a way like restarting the session like every day or every week there is no problem.
If it can be useful here's some information about the Grafana Kiosk mode, we have a NUC with Ubuntu 22.04 and when it's started opens Google Chrome with the Grafana page automatically and I want to keep the session open.

I did something similar by adding the following two lines to my /etc/grafana/grafana.ini:
login_maximum_inactive_lifetime_days = 365
token_rotation_interval_minutes = 525600

This attempted to set the timeouts to 1 year, although for some reason my Grafana still logs out "now and again". I am not sure why or the exact frequency but perhaps once or twice a month. The "solution" was good enough for my needs so I didn't try anything else!
